# how to get difference between two dates in sharepoint calculated column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

how to get different between two dates: column1 "joining date" column2 "leaving date", in  sharepoint calculated column as  "total experience of an employee"?

The desired output I'm searching is in this format for example: "2 days 2 months 2 years".

Comment: noted the mistakes @James Z, Will follow that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this formula should give you the answers that you are after

```
= DATEDIF([Date 1],[Date 2],"MD")&" Days "& DATEDIF([Date 1],[Date 2],"YM")  &" Months "& DATEDIF([Date 1],[Date 2],"Y") &" Years"
```

Steps:

1. Create a calculated column of type Single Line of text
2. Use the formula above.

Explanation:

Formula goes as

> DATEDIF(Start_date,End_date,"***Interval***")

Where ***interval*** can be:

- **Y**    Calculate the number of complete years
- **M**    Calculate the number of complete months
- **D**    Calculate the number of days
- **YM**   Calculate the number of months excluding years
- **MD**   Calculate the number of days excluding years and months
- **YD**   Calculate the number of days excluding years

For 2 dates like Date 1 (31/01/2020) and Date 2 (14/05/2020), the results will be:

> 14 Days 3 Months 0 Years

Comment: Thank you, this is useful. Please could you provide a reference as to where you got this information from? E.g. I don't see the DATEDIF function under the [syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#expressions).